# In python is it possible to insert string in text file after a certain character count?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, text

so open a text file, and insert text at a specific position (counted in characters) in the file?

I was thinking something along the lines of...

```
def insert_text(filename, text_to_insert, position):
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
         for line in file:
            for ch in line:
                if ch is position:
                    #insert text at position?
```

Comment: Read the entire content of file, change the content as your want and re-write the modified content to the file.

Comment: `if ch is position` is _wrong_

Comment: It's not possible to "edit" a text file.